# I can't get data from a public API : Access-control-allow-origin missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get data from a public API: 
    https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=1500&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=...

I don't understand why I'm getting a CORS error

Here a really simple Fiddle JS to see the error :  http://tpcg.io/51kVwI

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: A "public API" is not necessarily configured to respond with appropriate cross-origin headers. It may be public but designed to be used from servers, not browsers.

Comment: I ran this in chrome. I get no errors.

Comment: You just leaked your API key, might want to revoke that and generate a new one if you can...

Comment: The CoinMarketCap FAQ answers your question: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/faq/, Section "API Errors & Warnings", Question: "Why did I receive a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error while trying to use the API?"

Answer (score 5):

From: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide

Note: Making HTTP requests on the client side with Javascript is currently prohibited through CORS configuration. This is to protect your API Key which should not be visible to users of your application so your API Key is not stolen. Secure your API Key by routing calls through your own backend service.

They have example code for sending the request through a server, such as Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to hide API Key in Javascript, that's why the endpoint didn't allow client side (Javascript) to call it. You will need to make the request from server side. There are several serverless options with free tier out there, AWS Lambda, Google Cloud Functions, Azure Functions.